# Is "Share iPhone Analytics" enabled by default in iOS devices?

Tags: ios, analytics

In `iPhone Settings -> Privacy -> Analytics`, is the option "Share iPhone Analytics" enabled by default in iOS devices?
If yes, is "Share with App Developers" also enabled by default?
And if not, when exactly does the system ask user permission to enable/disable them first time?

Also, is there a feature in iOS allowing users to share their data with specific App Developers? For example, I want to share my device analytics with Twitter app, but not with Facebook application. I am guessing there is no such function, but it would be lovely to have it in future iOS versions.

Comment: The setting is system wide. You are asked whether you want to enable these settings when you first set up your phone. To be honest, the analytics that iOS gathers and shares with Facebook developers is nothing compared to what Facebook gathers themselves in the app. The analytics that you enable through the iOS setting are basically just application crashes, sessions (how often you use the app) and uninstalls.  Aside from crash data the other analytics are just shown to the developers as aggregate numbers, there is no user specific detail.

Comment: I just brought Facebook as an example, but I do agree on that point. So, to gather needed data on how your app is used by users, it is better to rely on data you gather yourself, rather than the App Store provides (apart from unique downloads and other  data related to the store itself)